# laravel/php (Crud) Connect a delete button to a function (routes)

Tags: php, arrays, database, sqlite, laravel-4

Hi There I have a table that iterates like so

```html
    <form method="get" action="search">
    <table class="bordered">
      <thead>
        <tr><th>No.</th><th>Post Username</th><th>Post Title</th><th>Post</th><th>Delete This post</th><td>Update This Post</td></tr>
      </thead>
      <tbody>
@foreach ($posts as $post)
        <tr>
          <td>{{{ $post->id }}}</td>
          <td>{{{ $post->post_username }}}</td>
          <td>{{{ $post->post_title }}}</td>
          <td>{{{ $post->post_message }}}</td>
          <td>
            <form method="post" action="{{{ url('delete_post_action') }}}">
            <input type="submit" value="{{ $post->id }}">Delete</td>
            </form>
          </td>
          <td><button name="update" value="{{ $post->id }}">Update</button></td>
        </tr>
@endforeach
    </tbody>
  </table>
  </form>
```

Which connects to this route.

```php
Route::post('delete_post_action', function()
{
    $sql = "select * from posts";
    $current_posts = DB::select($sql);

    $results=$current_posts;

    return View::make('pages.home')->withposts($results);
});

  function delete_item($id)
  {
    $id = $post->id;
    $sql = "delete from posts where id = ?";
    DB::delete($sql, array($id));
  }
```

I have no idea why it isn't working. It refreshes the page as intended and updates the table. But it is not deleting any rows!

Comment: But how would i reference the id? I tried $id = $post->id; but no dice.

Comment: from what i see you are not referencing the id properly.

Comment: Sorry for my ignorance, but I am not sure what you mean? how would I do so? Where would it go in the function? I am having some severe struggles here.

Answer (score 1):

```
Concatenate id you are injecting with your query would result in below 

        function delete_item($id)
          {
            $id = $post->id;
            $sql = "delete from posts where id='".$id."'";
            DB::delete($sql);
            return View::make('pages.home')
          }
```

Comment: let me add a return to it the function. ideally there should be return @ the end of the function